# Expressing the Power Set of the Positive Integers Using Modulo Two Arithmetic

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the power set of the positive integers still uncountable if you were to convert its members into sequences of zeros and ones using modulo two  arithmetic?

What I mean by this, is that you would treat the elements inside the subsets as numbers that can be expressed in modulo two arithmetic. As an example of this the set {1,2,3} would turn into {1,0,1}.

Comment: Expressing a set using a different representation doesn't change the cardinality.

Comment: The sequence of binary strings is uncountable (they are in correspondence with the real numbers between $0$ and $1$).  I don't understand your second interpretation.

Comment: Also, you presumably mean base-$2$ arithmetic, not mod $2$..

Comment: @quasi  the question is poorly worded, but I assume the OP does mean $\pmod 2$.  The set $\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$ would become $\{1,0,1,0,\cdots\}$ as would the set $\{3,4,5,\cdots\}$.

Comment: What do you mean by using modulo $2$ arithmetic on a set?

Comment: @lulu: Well, if that's the intent, then you end up with a set of two elements!

Comment: @quasi  Not at all.  $\{2,4,6,\cdots\}$ maps to $\{0,0,0\cdots\}$.  $\{1,3,6\}$ maps to $\{1,1,0\}$ and so on.

Comment: @lulu: I was interpreting braces as set braces, but you apparently mean sequences.

Comment: @LorenzoGilBadiola As you can see from the comments your question is not clear.  Can you confirm or reject my reading of your first interpretation?  Can you clarify your second?

Comment: I suspect you mean to replace each set with its indicator function, but that has nothing whatever to do with the use of modulo $2$ arithmetic.

Comment: @quasi  Yes...I am (carelessly) using braces for both sets and sequences.

Comment: Your reading of the first part is right. What I mean by the second part is to remove the braces and commas of the set {1,2,3} and consider it as one number.

Comment: Well, what does it matter how I write the sequence?  Or are you saying that under the second interpretation the set of even numbers would map to the number $0$?

Comment: In other words, {1,2,3} would turn into 123.

Comment: But why be unclear?  Edit your question to include explicit examples of what you mean.

Comment: What?  That makes no sense.  $2,3$ aren't $\pmod 2$ values.

Comment: Using base two arithmetic, the number 123, should turn into 1.

Comment: So the example in your post is wrong?  Please correct it.  And include an example to show what you'd do with an infinite subset, like $\mathbb N$.

Comment: All the confusion aside, go back to my first comment.  For some reason you switched the order of your "interpretations" so what I called second is now your first and my comment applies to your current second.  Do you see how that shows that this is uncountable?

Comment: I think you should delete your "first interpretation".  Nobody can sort out what you mean by it (including you, I expect).

Comment: Is the bolded first paragraph an _exact_ quote of an exercise someone has posed for you? Or is it translated from a language other than English. (If the word you represent as "sequences" could instead mean "sets", the problem would make a lot more sense to me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U$ be the uncoutable set of all sets of positive integers.

First interpretation: 
As far as I understand, you transform any finite set into $1$ or $0$ depending on the parity of its biggest element. How you transform infinite sets, such as the set of all even numbers $2\mathbb{N}$, for instance, remains unclear.

Second interpretation:
This time you map $U$ onto $V=\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$.
$V$ is uncountable.

Comment: The integers aren't uncountable

Comment: @Avi Steiner . Correct. I didn't say otherwise, did I?

Comment: you did not. I misread something. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be a little more careful, here.

One potential issue is that your transformation is not well-defined. For example the sets $\{2,1\}$ and $\{1,2\}$ are equal, but the sequences $\langle 0,1\rangle$ and $\langle 1,0\rangle$ are ***not***. One fix for this is to define the transformation (say $f$) recursively as follows:

- If $A=\emptyset,$ then let $f(A)=\emptyset.$
- Otherwise, we define $f(A)$ recursively as follows: Let the first entry of $f(A)$ be the least element of $A,$ *modulo* $2$. If there are any elements of $A$ which haven't yet been given a corresponding entry of $f(A),$ then let the next entry of $f(A)$ be the least such element of $A$--that is, the least element of $A$ which hasn't yet been given a corresponding entry of $f(A)$--*modulo* $2$.

By recursion, to each set $A$ of positive integers, we have assigned a (possibly finite) sequence $f(A)$ of $0$s and $1$s. It turns out that *any* such sequence has the form $f(A)$ for some such $A,$ though I leave the proof of this to you.

---

There is another interesting point, the proof of which I leave to you. Given any non-empty set $A$ of positive integers, there exist *infinitely-many* distinct sets $B$ of positive integers such that $f(A)=f(B).$ Consequently, this transformation is ***far*** from being one-to-one.

However, despite that, even if we restrict our consideration to the infinite sets of positive integers, the range of the transformation is $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N},$ which can be shown to be equinumerous to the real interval $[0,1],$ and hence uncountable.

In particular, given $a:=\langle a_n\rangle_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that $a_n\in\{0,1\}$ for all $n\in\Bbb N,$ define $$g(a):=\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}\frac{a_n}{2^n}.$$ It can be shown that $a\mapsto g(a)$ is a bijection $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}\to[0,1],$ as desired.

---

Obviously, uncountability need not be inherited by the range of *every* function on a given uncountable set. For example, let $\mathcal U$ be any uncountable set, and define $h:\mathcal{U}\to\{\emptyset\}$ by $h(A)=\emptyset$ for all $A\in\mathcal U.$